# A question on countably compact space under CH

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The question is also posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124778/a-question-on-countably-compact-space). 
A  regular space $X$ is

1. star compact (which implies pseudocompact)
2. with $G_\delta$-diagonal
3. star countable
4. first countable
5. $e(X)\le \aleph_0$ ( in fact it implies star countable)
6. $|X|=\aleph_1$
7. Čech-complete

My question is this: Under CH, Must $X$ be countably compact?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: However, under CH, $\mathfrak d=\aleph_1$, so it cannot be true in this question. Is it right?

Comment: Ach! You’re right: I had the consistency results in the other question turned around in my mind.

Comment: For what it’s worth, [this example](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/332119/12042) seems to have all of these properties (under CH) except the $G_\delta$-diagonal, so you will definitely need that.

Comment: @paul is it enought for you $X$ is star compact $\iff$ $X$ countable compact